How to show that RMSE is more sensitive to outliers than the MAE?
I am reading this book where it states that for $\ell_p$ norms:

The higher the norm index, the more it focuses on large values and
neglects small ones. This is why the RMSE is more sensitive to
outliers than the MAE.

However I fail it to see why this is true.
I am aware of this question, but I am searching for a mathematical proof.

For $f(x)=x^p$, $f'(x)=px^{p-1}$, which increases in $p$ (for $|x|\geq1$).

There can be no mathematical proof if there is no precise mathematical statement.
